# View two geometry columns together in pgAdmin Geometry Viewer

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I have two geometry columns like this:

[image]

How can I see them together in the Geometry Viewer?
If i select all rows it shows only one column at a time.

Comment: I don't think you can do that - try using QGIS

Comment: You should check out dbeaver community edition.  It's free and has a geometry viewer that allows you to select and view multiple geometries at once, like you're describing.  It saves you the step of collecting or unioning the geometries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not directly, but you can construct a new geometry - or a geometry collection - containing the two geometries using `st_collect`

```sql
select st_collect('point(1 1)'::geometry, 'linestring(0 0, 0 1)'::geometry)
```

or more likely from two tables

```sql
select st_collect(a.geom,b.geom)   
from a join b on ...
```

[image]